# Microsoft Graph. How to receive owner's information for remote items

Tags: c#, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I use Microsoft Graph for browse user OneDrive folders and files (DriveItem in terms of Microsoft Graph). When I receive DriveItem information, I try to read its owner: name and e-mail. 
For shared file/folder I use [`Item.Shared.Owner.User.Id`](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/shared), for local file/folder I use [`Item.CreatedBy.User.Id`](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem). For this Id I can read user's information:

`GraphServiceClient.Users[Id].Request().GetAsync();`

But, I have problem with for remote DriveItem. I understand that at first I should read remote item information by data from [RemoteItem structure](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/remoteitem). 
So, at first I read its:

`var remote = await GraphServiceClient.Drives[Item.RemoteItem.ParentReference.DriveId].Items[Item.RemoteItem.Id].Request().GetAsync();`

Then I try to get remote item owner:

`GraphServiceClient.Users[remote.CreatedBy.User.Id].Request().GetAsync();`

But I receive signed-in user information instead the remote owner! As if I call:

`GraphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();`

Why? And how to receive owner's information for OneDrive remote items?

Comment: is it possible that the calling identity is the one that actually created the remote item you're querying?

Comment: @Brad, yes new item was created at 30 minute before the query, but its owner is old OneDrive user. is it problem?

Comment: Do I use right API method? Will `GraphServiceClient.Users[RemoteOwnerId].Request().GetAsync();` return owner account info?

Comment: The `drive` object should have an `owner` property that you could use for your purpose.

Comment: @Brad, for user default drive `owner` is filled, but for remote drive is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `GraphServiceClient.Users[RemoteOwnerId].Request().GetAsync()‌` can't be used for receiving info about owner of remote `DriveItem` at all.
And all info should be returned by request:

`var remote = await GraphServiceClient.Drives[RemoteDriveId].Items[RemoteItemId].Request().GetAsync();`

But, Microsoft Graph `v1.0` returns empty `remote.Shared.Owner.User`. Only Microsoft Graph `beta` returns this structure with filled `displayName`! Bug?

Next question: How to receive e-mail and photo for owner of remote item?